# Total Disk Space JDK 1.4

Tags: java, filesystems, java1.4

Is there a way for me to know the total space on a hard disk using JDK 1.4? Apache commons does not provide a similar functionality. Remember, I need to use it with a JDK 1.4 application.

Many thanks.

**Update:**
I have tried to use Sigar, but it's not compatible with JDK 1.4.2_08. I downloaded Sigar's source code in order to build it with my version of Java, but I couldn't resolve the dependencies referenced in the build.xml.

Comment: Right click on folder and check the size, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: No. It's not what he's asking for

Comment: Java 1.4 is **ancient**. Still using it is a *maintenance*, *development* **and** *security* nightmare. That's at least 3 *major* reasons to upgrade. Tell that to your boss *every time* you're forced to do some ugly hacks because you're still using a Java version that was released *11 years ago* (even Java 5 is already 9 years old!)

Comment: We're still using it 'cause we have some embedded hardware that has a special version of Java (The processor is ARM based). We need to buy a license for a newer version of Java, which is not feasible now.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `File` disk space methods were only added in Java 6, I suspect your only option is to invoke a OS-specific binary e.g.

```
df -k /
```

(for Linux)

The amount of effort you need to expend on implementing such a solution *may* be better spent moving your application to a recent JDK/JRE (you may have limitations I'm not aware of, however, so please ignore if so!)

Comment: I already prepared a shell script to do it:
df -H -P /root | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }'

The problem is that the result of the above is inconsistent among different hardware/distributions...

Comment: @MouhammedSoueidane - Either upgrade to Java 6/7 ... or wear the cost / pain of dealing with inconsistent results from external commands.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite familiar with windows systems, but for linux you may get current `Runtime` and creating new process that will execute a system command.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("df -h");
```

You can get output of command from input stream and then parse output to determine disk space

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
```

Make sure you wait for process to exit and control process exit value. Linux commands return 0 when command execution is success.

```
int procReturn = proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: I already prepared a shell script to do it: df -H -P /root | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' The problem is that the result of the above is inconsistent among different hardware/distributions...

Comment: Dont use script for grabbing specific part of the output. Get all output "df -h" in reader object. Then parse it within java. Java has more options parsing text.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got what I needed using Sigar 1.6.2 which works with my Java version. I got what I needed using the following line of code:

```
System.out.println("Disk usage on moint point drive / is "+sigar.getFileSystemUsage("/root"));
```

**Output:**

```
Disk usage on moint point drive / is  {DiskQueue=-1.0, DiskReadBytes=0, DiskWriteBytes=0, Free=2198724, DiskWrites=0, UsePercent=0.71, DiskReads=0, Files=425152, Used=4489992, Avail=1858952, FreeFiles=251740, DiskServiceTime=-1.0, Total=6688716}
Finished
```